# How to add existing profile in the mapper configuration using Refection(In a generic way)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection, automapper

I have a separate classes for mapping between source and destination. For e.g.

RegistrationMapping:

```
public class RegistrationMapping
{
    public static void Map(IProfileExpression profile)
    {
       profile.CreateMap<DB_Registration, Registration>()
            .ForMember(x => x.EMP_ID, map => map.MapFrom(c => c.employeeID))
            .ForMember(x => x.MOB_NO, map => map.MapFrom(c => c.Mobile))
            .ForMember(x => x.EMAIL_ID, map => map.MapFrom(c => c.EmailID))
     }
}
```

In a similar fashion, I have classes for other mappings as well.

Now in my repository, I want to use like this,

```
// I want to achieve below code in a generic way. 
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(/*RegistrationMapping goes here*/)); 
var mappedConfigurations = config.GetAllTypeMaps(); // This line of code is needed for my other purpose(get unmapped properties)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

AutoMapper allows profiles to be loaded by passing the assembly, the assembly name, or type contained in the assembly.

Your RegistrationMapping class and others have to be inherited from AutoMapper.Profile.

You can load your profiles like this:

By type:

```
Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfile<RegistrationMapping>()); 
Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfile(typeof(RegistrationMapping)));
```

By instance:

```
Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfiles(new List<Profile> { new RegistrationMapping() })); 
Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfile(new RegistrationMapping()));
```

By assembly name:

```
Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddMaps("MyApplication.RegistrationMapping"));
Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddMaps(new string[] {"MyApplication.RegistrationMapping"}));
```

By assembly:

```
Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddMaps(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
```

If you want to load all profiles from loaded assemblies:

```
var profiles = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes().Where(type => typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(type)));
Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddMaps(profiles));
```

For more information please see also the [AutoMapper Configuration](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html) documentation and the [source code](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/Configuration/MapperConfigurationExpression.cs).

Comment: I don't want to inherit the RegistrationMapping class directly into the Mapper Configuration. I wanted it to implement using Refection.

Comment: I still don't understand your question what you are trying to achieve. Instead of scanning the assembly, would you like to find all profiles by reflection and then register? If so, please see the updated answer how to find all profiles in all loaded assemblies.